# How To Combine Two ArrayAdapter Into Single ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm stuck in making `ArrayAdapter` in Android...

**The problem is like this:**

I have two `ArrayAdapter<String>.`..
The first one, It consist of the list of men, and the second one the list of women..
I want to combine both of them so it will become single `ArrayAdapter` and I want to show it...

My friends suggest me that I should combine the `ArrayList<String>` which include the list of men and women, for example:

```
public ArrayList<String> listOfPeople;
listofPeople = listOfMen;
listCampur.addAll(listOfWomen);
list.SetAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listOfPeople));
```

Yes, it looks similar like that.. 
listOfMen consist of the men's name and listOfWomen consist of the women's name..

I got that the idea, but the case is I want the different layout of those lists..
I mean I have two gender icons which represents of those lists...
So when the list consist of men, it will show the male symbol for example...

So, how to do this?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

In you case you can set image depending on position.
let i have 5 men and 9 women list
I have used

```
listCampur.addAll(listOfWomen);
```

then in my list i will get list of 14 members out of these first 5 are men and next 9 are women

in getView() method i can get the position of view write a condition if(position<4) set men image otherwise set women image.

Another option is use custom listview

Comment: uhm, using the condition with if is makes sense..
But, I have piut those lists in two ArrayAdapter...
so is it possible to combine them???

Comment: craete a single arrayadapter after combining both men and women lists

Comment: But, I want the different layout in that combination of list..
I follow this link [link](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#overview_listview) in the section ListActivity with own layout. And back to my case, I want the different layout based on the gender

Comment: I found that it's using condition to check whether it's in men group or women group. But, I still don't know the idea..